# Show image value from picture box to data grid view

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

I've converted image from RGB to YCbCr, and split the YCbCr image into 8x8 pixels.
Now I want to show the Y value from every blocks of image in **dataGridView**. How to show Y value in dataGridView?

Comment: How do you want to show Y? As a number? Where is the problem? Add 8 rows with 8 cells..?

Comment: How did you convert an image from RGB to YCbCr? If you use formula to calculate Y,Cb,Cr then you can use the values to fill the DGV.